# メモリ関連のドライバの確認法

Tags: linux

メーカー製のボード（i.mx6使用）で組込Linuxを使用しています。
メーカーより、ボード上のeMMCが保守化により、容量が4GBから8GBに変更の案内が来ました。
それに伴い、Linuxにパッチが必要になり、それはメーカーで行ってもらいました。
その受け入れ検査をしたいのですが、どの様な確認をしたら良いでしょうか？

今、考えているのは
・システムが起動すること
・メモリ容量を確認し、正しく認識できていること
です。
他に何を確認したら良いでしょうか？確認用ツールが有るでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

その後、調査した内容を自己回答で書きます。
ボードのソフトのユーザーマニュアルに、その会社が行っているテスト内容がありました。
以下の内容を確認していました。
・正しくマウントされていること
・コンソールでマウント先に移動出来ること
・lsコマンドでファイル一覧が見れること
・mkdirコマンドでディレクトリが作成できること
・rm -rf で上記ディレクトリが削除出来ること

といった内容です。
確認用ツールソフトが有るわけでは無いようです。